# Print a line in according to a timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp

I coded this:

```
def show_line(self):
    next_line = self.curr_line + 1
    self.line = self.lines[self.curr_line]
    y = self.line.split(' ')
    z = self.lines[next_line].split(' ')
    d1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(y[0]))
    d2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(z[0]))
    d3 = d2-d1  
    d3s = str(d3)
    sleep_time = int(float(d3s[6::]))*1000
    print_on_screen(self.line)
    glib.timeout_add(sleep_time, self.show_line)
    self.curr_line += 1
    return False
```

where "line" is an array which contains the lines of the file (I used
readlines() ).
In each of these lines, there is the timestamp, used to display the strings
on screen in according with the difference between two of them (d3).

The problem is that is displayed the 1st line, 3rd one, 5th one and so on
and not respecting the timestamp. 
Suggestions?

Franco

Comment: What actually is wrong with the above? Your telling us what  your trying to do but not what is wrong.

Comment: I'm curious about the glib.timeout_add. Why are you using this ? One problem is that when the timeout finish, it calls you function self.showline, hence the linejust after : "self.curr_line += 1" is never executed...

Comment: @Tom97531 that is incorrect. The lines `self.curr_line += 1` and `return False` most definitely do get executed. Calling `glib.timeout_add` (or `gobject.timeout_add` as it seems to be called for me) doesn't somehow prevent the rest of the function from executing.

Answer (score 2):

You are converting the timestamps to numbers of milliseconds but you are doing it incorrectly:

```
d3s = str(d3)
sleep_time = int(float(d3s[6::]))*1000
```

I cannot imagine why you are doing this by converting the timestamp to a string, extracting some characters out of it, then converting it to a float, and then converting again, this time to an integer. This code is not clear, but you certainly have an error in there: why are you discarding the first 6 characters of the string?

The correct way to convert a `datetime.timedelta` to milliseconds is:

```
sleep_time = d3.total_seconds()*1000
```

You have other problems with your code:

- You should use `utcfromtimestamp`, not `fromtimestamp`. Converting the timestamps to local time introduces a dependancy on the local time zone with all of the pitfalls that come with that. You might have problems calculating the difference between 2 timestamps that straddle a daylist savings time boundary, for example. There is no need to use local time here. You might as well just work in UTC.
- Actually you don't really need to convert the timestamps to `datetime.datetime` objects at all. Why don't you just subtract the timestamps directly?
- You have a bug when you get to the penultimate line.